# Looping over several input files in R

Tags: raster, r, loop, regression

Please help a beginner in R

I am trying to do some regression analysis in R  between pairs of precipitation and NDVI rasters. I got the regression to work, and now I would like to loop this over all the rasters, pair-wise. All my data is labelled NDVI0101, pre0101, NDVI0102, pre0102.....

Is there a way to loop so that the regression is preformed between two rasters with the same date, and which also saves the output residual-file with the date?

Here is my code:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

#set working directory
setwd("C:/users/neija/documents/Rworkingfolder")

#load raster
ndvi <- raster("rdata/ndvi/ndvi0101.tif")
pre <- raster("rdata/precip/pre0101.tif")

#extract values from raster into a vector
y <-getValues(ndvi)
prere <- resample(pre, ndvi, method="bilinear")
x <-getValues(prere)
y[which(is.na(x))]<-NA 

#combine in data frame
f<-data.frame(x,y)

model<-lm(x~y,data = f)
summary(model)

#extract residuals
r <- ndvi 
r [] <- residuals.lm(model)
writeRaster (r, file = "res0101.asc")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant solution but it will work if they're both in the same folder, additionally if you have a small set of "years" you could pass them into a vector and construct the file paths from that. I find `list.files` is one of the most important functions to know when iterating through folders and folders of rasters:

```
ndvi<-"ndvi"
pre<-"pre"

#find all tifs in your directory
dir<-"C:/users/neija/documents/Rworkingfolder"
#get a list of all files with ndvi in the name in your directory
files<-list.files(path=dir, pattern='ndvi', full.names = TRUE)

for (file in files){
  name <- file
  subname<-sub(ndvi,pre,file)
  srraster<-stack(file,subname)
  #rest of your code....
  #can refer to ndvi as
  #srraster[[1]]
  #and pre as ssraster[[2]]
  #change the name of the save file
  savename<-sub("res",ndvi,basename(file))
  writeRaster(r,file=savename)

}
```

Comment: One could use regexp if they are in different folders? "^[a-zA-Z]{1,5}[0-9]{1,5}.tif$"

Comment: I think I would then use something to split the path and then use paste0 if in different folders. I find Python better for working with strings imo